# Issue with DioError in flutter project on github

Tags: flutter

I'm having this error in my github pipeline:
• 'DioError' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use DioException instead. This will be removed in 6.0.0 • deprecated_member_use
Any ideas, how to fix? For now name 'DioException' isn't defined in my project, so in project I don't have any errors.

```
pubspec.yaml:
name: 
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: "none"
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.1 <4.0.0"
  flutter: 3.10.1

dependencies:
  app_settings: 4.2.0
  encrypt: 5.0.1
  fade_shimmer: 2.2.0
  fimber: 0.6.6
  firebase_core: 2.13.0

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_bloc: 8.1.3
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_secure_storage: 8.0.0
  flutter_svg: 2.0.6
  freezed: 2.3.4
  get_it: 7.6.0
  go_router: 7.1.1
  google_fonts: 4.0.4
  google_sign_in: 6.1.1
  injectable: 2.1.1
  intl: any
  json_annotation: 4.8.1
  logger: 1.3.0
  lottie: 2.3.2
  percent_indicator: 4.2.2
  retrofit: 4.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: 2.4.4
  flutter_gen_runner: 5.3.1
  flutter_lints: 2.0.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  injectable_generator: 2.1.5
  json_serializable: 6.7.0
  retrofit_generator: 7.0.1
  test: any

flutter_gen:
  output: lib/generated
  line_length: 120
  integrations:
    flutter_svg: true
    langs: false
    lottie: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/svgs/
    - assets/lottie/
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Dio` pub version is [5.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) and if you scroll down the documentation you will arrive at "Handling Errors" section. As you can see in this section, the pub gives some help to `try/catch` errors, implementing the `DioException` with which `Dio` wraps errors.
As far as I know, in the future version `6.0` of `Dio` the `DioError` will not be longer supported so, you should start replacing your `DioError` with `DioException`.

This is what the documentation reports with code, I highly suggest you to read it even if this piece of code works.

```
try {
  // 404
  await dio.get('https://api.pub.dev/not-exist');
} on DioException catch (e) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
  if (e.response != null) {
    print(e.response.data)
    print(e.response.headers)
    print(e.response.requestOptions)
 } else {
   // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
   print(e.requestOptions)
   print(e.message)
 }
}
```

You can follow the official documentation (link above) to learn more and how to implement it correctly in your project.

If following the documentation doesn't solve your error, please provide some code example and update your question so I can update my answer, happy coding!

Comment: With  DioException  I have an error 'DioException' isn't defined

Comment: Can you show me your pubspecl.yaml ? @Evgen

Comment: shared pubspec.yaml in post

Comment: I cant' find your Dio pub in your pubspec.yaml ? Are you sure you added it to your project ?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/cfug/dio/commit/67b18d3a448ee1e50f63dd27b4e27b2059a665ab) seems like yesterday they fixed something in DioException, maybe in some days they will update the pub

Comment: Definitely, it concerns to changes you mentioned. Thanks for help! I use Dio through retrofit.

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know if this will be solved by the team. By using retrofit you will have to wait until Dio updates and until Retrofit updates sequently. Happy coding!

Comment: flutter pub upgrade resolved this problem

Comment: Yep, they pushed an update yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

@Deprecated('Use DioException instead. This will be removed in 6.0.0')
typedef DioError = DioException;

Reference: https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/DioError.html